# How to Set AngularJs Controller Properties from MVC4 ActionResult

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 Controller that loads and object and sends it to a View for editing.  The Edit form view has a dropdown control containing US States which is bound to an AngularJS Controller property called containing an array of states.

I want set the AngularJS property $scope.SelectedState from the View Model so that the dropdown displays the correct state.  I cannot find a way to pass the MVC Model State Value cleanly to the AngularJS Controller Property.  Thanks

```
$scope.SelectedState= {{I want to set this value from the MVC Model}};
```

HTML Below

```
  <label for="States" class="control-label col-md-2">States</label>
  <div class="controls col-md-4">
    <select ng-model="SelectedState" id="States" class="form-control" ng-options="st.abbreviation + ' - ' + st.name for st in States.USStates track by st.abbreviation">
      <option value="">-- Choose State --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="SelectedState" name="SelectedState" value="{{SelectedState}}" />
  </div>
```

Here is a [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uQVD4rPxNEL9ChsTAPj7?p=preview) of the solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label for="States" class="control-label col-md-2">States</label>

    //convert your Model.State to Json and set States using ng-init
    <div class="controls col-md-4" ng-init="States = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.State))">
      <select ng-init=n g-model="SelectedState" id="States" class="form-control" ng-options="st.abbreviation + ' - ' + st.name for st in States.USStates track by st.abbreviation">
        <option value="">-- Choose State --</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" id="SelectedState" name="SelectedState" value="{{SelectedState}}" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the html: `<div ng-init="SelectedState = @(Model.SelectedState)"></div>`
Replace `@(Model.SelectedState)` with whatever from your MVC model. My example is in Razor.